# How use a defined PPT template on PPTXGEN

Tags: pptxgenjs

I have a defined template, and I want to use it on the ppt exported using PPTXGEN LIBRARY.
is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you convert your template to (i.e. implement your template in) Javascript.

I found a python package here: [python-pptx-text-replacer](https://github.com/fschaeck/python-pptx-text-replacer)

If you are in an company, there's a commercial package called [docxtemplate](https://docxtemplater.com/faq/#plan-comparison-table).